# Как применить шрифт с Google Fonts?

Tags: html, css, шрифты, google-fonts

```
<p>Привет!</p>
```

Как с помощью CSS поставить шрифт, если у тебя уже есть с GoogleFonts шрифты?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если Вы уже добавили/импортировали шрифт с [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto), то Вам достаточно применить его к нужному Вам элементу (p) или же ко всему документу (body):

```css
p:first-of-type {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<p>Привет шрифту Roboto!</p>
<p>а тут без шрифта</p>
```